# Reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric or transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let S be the relation on the set of integers and xSy is defined as x and y yield the same remainder when divided by 3.

Determine whether the relation is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric or transitive. Give a counterexample if your answer is "No".

How to know that the number of x and y? Sorry, i have no idea to start with this kind of question.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of the terms "[reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), [irreflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Related_terms), [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation), [asymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation), and [antisymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) or [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)"? This question is essentially making you carefully apply the definitions to a specific relation.

Comment: More fundamentally, first know that a "(binary) [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on a set" $S$ is itself a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ are elements of $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation is nothing but $xRy \iff x\equiv y(mod 3)$ i.e $x Ry \iff x-y$ is divisible by $3$..which is an equivalence relation

Definitely not antisymmetric $8 R 14$ and $14 R 8$ but $8\neq 14$

Comment: thanks! what is the easier way to know the Reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric or transitive for this question?

Comment: I dont get your question